# Prettier (VSCode) auto adding semicolons rather than parentheses after the word "return" in React JS

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I don't know what happens but yesterday, Prettier extension still adding parentheses after "return" without me having to typing it out. But today, it decided to turn those in to semicolons instead.

Example:
When I type:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return 
  <div>
    <h1>
      Hello World
    </h1>
  </div>
}
```

Prettier supposed to add (), like this:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But for some reasons that I want to scream, it now works like this:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return;
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>;
};
```

I try deleting the setting json file to reset the formatting but to no avail. Help would be so much appreciated.